# How do I fix Newton failed to find minimum in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a series of ARGOS data from various individual animals. I am using the R package [aniMotum](https://ianjonsen.r-universe.dev/articles/aniMotum/Move_persistence_models.html) (previously foiegras) to create move persistence maps like this example output from the documentation. My goal is to be able to create one of these maps for each animal in my dataframe. [image: aniMotum move persistence]

When I adapt the example code to my tracking data, it fails on some tracks and not others. When it fails, I receive a series of errors like these

> Error in newton(par = c(X = 4205.28883097774, X = -5904.86998464547, X = 4204.95187507608,  :
> Newton failed to find minimum.

And a final error

> Warning message:
> The optimiser failed. Try simplifying the model with the following argument:
> `map = list(rho_o = factor(NA))`

Here is a sample of the code I used

```
library(aniMotum)
library(tidyverse)
movePersistence <- readRDS("newton_error.rds")


x <-fit_ssm(movePersistence,
        vmax = 3,
        model = "mp",
        time.step = 2,
        control = ssm_control(verbose = 2)
)

aniMotum::map(x, what = "p", normalise = TRUE, silent = TRUE)
```

From what I can tell, the issue is occurring from the Newton function in the [TMB package](https://rdrr.io/cran/TMB/src/R/TMB.R) (a dependency of Animotum). I have noticed that if I change the *time.step* value, it will change the number of errors I get. For example, on track 14, I get 13 Newton errors with a step of 2 but none with a step of 12. I am using 2 as it gives a better approximation than 12. I did try my whole dataset at various steps and each time, different tracks fail. I also tried changing the tolerance and number of iterations in the *ssm_control* but that was more of a hail-Mary approach that was not working.

Here is a `dput()` of track 14 to reproduce the errors on a smaller scale using the above code - https://pastebin.com/xMXzdPDh - if anyone has some recommendations I would greatly appreciate it as I do not understand the inconsistent results.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the packages you mentioned but I'll try to shed some light on the error message. The business about the failed optimization is probably that the tracking package is trying to fit a model onto the data points, which it will then use to tell how to color the points and/or how big to make them (I'm guessing about that). The model fitting has failed -- that can mean different things, one common cause is that the start point for the iterations isn't close enough to a solution, and the iterations went off into never-never land.

Comment: Another is that the function which tells how well the model fits the data (the goodness of fit function or figure of merit) has bumps and curves that are unexpected by the optimization algorithm. Whatever the cause, my guess is that the tracks for which it works and the ones for which it doesn't work are noticeably different. Try plotting the successful and failed tracks and see what's different about them.

Comment: About getting to a solution for the failed ones, my main advice is to try to find someone who knows about the tracking package specifically. It's likely you won't find such a person on Stackoverflow; if the tracking package has a Github page, try posting an issue on its issue tracker, possibly also try posting a message to the r-help mailing list and mention the package name in the subject line. Good luck.

Comment: @RobertDodier thank you for providing a bit more statistical understanding to the model. I was trying to watch some videos on Newton modeling and this has helped to clarify it. I did try plotting them and could not see anything out of the ordinary unfortunately. I wasn't aware of the r-help mailing list so I will give that a go first before posting an issue on Github (as I feel it is more a bug with my data/code than an issue with the package)